# Fitting a multiple linear regression in R

Tags: r, fitting, lm

I have annual mean temperature and precipitation data from 1901 to 2015:

[image: excel spreadsheet data]

I want to do a multiple linear regression:

```
fit<-lm(pr_ann ~ tas_ann + Year, data = mexico_ann)
```

But it gives me this problem:

[image: result]

Can someone help me?

Comment: The year in the model was treated as categorical. Maybe you want  year to be the continuous. So find a way to tell R that year is continuous.

Comment: ok do you have a suggestion how to do it? i am sorry but i am really new to r

Comment: Sorry I ma new to r also. I just learned how to convert continue to category by `factor()` and have not find its inverse. `as.numeric(as.character(f))` ?

Comment: If you are new to R, a good place to start is here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf As for your problem, have a look at `?as.numeric()` or `?as.integer()`. Look at `?str()` as well.

Comment: Just try mexico_ann$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(mexico_ann$Year)) to convert Year to a numeric variable. Or use as.integer() instead of as.numeric() in the command I suggested.

Comment: ok i try to convert it, still there is a problem with the results:

Comment: You have time series data . You might want to look at https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf for a more general way of  doing " regression analysis" as it details some pitfalls of OLS

Comment: 1) the real problem here is not how to use R, but the fact that you're using the wrong statistical model. This is time series data, not cross-sectional data, thus the use of the multiple linear regression model (and its estimation with OLS) is fundamentals flawed. Talk to your advisor or manager, and demand that you are given proper  training (and if they refuse, look for a better position...but I digress). 2) Concerning why you still get a NA, post a new question containing a MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) on Stack Overflow. This is not the right place for programming questions.

Comment: If you can replace the screenshot image in your question with text data, I can run it trough my zunzun.com 3D "function finder" to perform an equation search.